# flexibly ellipsized two spaces in one area according to the text length

Tags: html, css, web

I want to flexibly ellipsized two spaces in one area according to the text length  on my website. In the case of a code pen page(https://codepen.io/jiniC/pen/QWpzOeo), I want to abbreviate only the text1 text while all the text in the text2 area is exposed.

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="item text1">ellipsis test ellipsis test ellipsis test ellipsis test</span>
  <span class="ico">&nbsp|&nbsp</span>
  <span class="item text2">full text</span>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
```

I know that it is possible to some extent by giving the min-width value to the item area. However, if min-width is given, blank space is left when the text is less than the min-width value. I want the text to be fully exposed up to a certain length, even though there is no margin when the length is short.

That is, I do not want the following situation:
[image]

Is this possible only with styling?

Here are some examples of different exposures depending on the text length I want.
[text1]|[text2]
[Short Short text1]|[text2]
[Very long text1 that has to be elli...]|[Short text2]
[text1]|[Very long text2 that has to be ellipsized...]
[Very long text1 that h...][Very long text2 that h...]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right path, but not quite sure how you can achieve this unless you use max-width for items.
See if this helps: https://www.benmarshall.me/max-character-length-ellipsis-css/